# Grep from script in bash

Tags: regex, bash, grep

As part of training and improve my bash skills, I am trying to set the bellow basic bash script to test a value/variable read from stdin with grep.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A COMPLIANCE=( [special_characters]="[^a-zA-Z0-9_]|[[:blank:]]" )

read -sp "Enter Password: " password
echo

for rule in "${!COMPLIANCE[@]}"; do
    grep -E "\"${COMPLIANCE[${rule}]}\"" <<< "\"${password}\""; exit="${?}"
    if [[ "${exit}" -gt 0 ]]; then echo "status ${exit}: ${rule} not compliant"; fi;
done
```

When I run the grep command directly from terminal with trivial text value that include a special character, it works

```
 grep -E "[^a-zA-Z0-9_]|[[:blank:]]" <<< "abc@"
```

result: abc@

But the same command doesnot work when included in a script.

I am also curious that the script do work when a single special character is provided such as "@". So I added the "+" quantifier to the regex but still with no success

I thought there were some issue with the regex format may be with [[:blank:]] as explained here https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html. But again with no probing result to my issue.

I use a centos stream 9 box.

Thanks

Comment: Note that "blank" characters are already included in `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Comment: did you check your code at https://shellcheck.net ? Good luck.

Comment: Remove the extra, escaped double-quotes from both the `grep` argument and the here-string. You can also do this directly in bash with `if ! [[ "$password" =~ ${COMPLIANCE[${rule}]} ]]; then echo "${rule} not compliant"; fi`

Comment: Take care that the right-hand side of `[[ $string =~ $pattern ]]` is **not quoted**.

Comment: According to your `grep` in your script, the password needs to have a substring which  starts with a double quote, but the password you supply probably does not contain a quote. Run the code with `set -x` to check this. OTOH, The grep command on the command line does not refer to any double quotes, so you are comparing apples with pears here. Aside from this, `grep` is IMO a poor choice for this task, since bash can do extended regular expressions itself. No need to spawn a child process.

Comment: To recreate an equivalent situation on the command line, you would have to use something like `grep -E "\"[^a-zA-Z0-9_]|[[:blank:]]\"" <<< "abc@"`, or - easier to read - `grep -E '"[^a-zA-Z0-9_]|[[:blank:]]"' <<< "abc@"`

Comment: @GordonDavisson It works after removing extra double-quotes. But I did with the direct if statement. I also added IFS= to preserve leading and/or ending whitespace and the -r option to the read command to preserve eventual backslash. Don't hésitate to give the answer bellow so I could tag it as accepted and you will receive point award for your help. thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

As @GordonDavisson pointed out, I removed the extra double quotes and it works. But I did with a direct statement.
I also added to the read cmd line IFS= to preserve leading and/or ending whitespace and the -r option to preserve eventual backslash.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A COMPLIANCE=( [special_characters]="[^a-zA-Z0-9_]|[[:blank:]]" )

IFS= read -srep "Enter Password for user \`${user}\`: $(echo $'\n> ')" password
printf "\n"

echo

for rule in "${!COMPLIANCE[@]}"; do
    if ! [[ "${password}" =~ ${COMPLIANCE[${rule}]} ]]; then
        echo "${rule} not compliant"
    fi
done
```